# How to solve this integral equation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

While solving a question, I got stuck at

> $$\dfrac{\int_{0}^{1}{\dfrac{\ln^2\left(x\right)}{\left(1-x\right)^2}}dx}{\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\ln\left(x\right)}{\left(1-x\right)x}}dx}$$

How should I proceed, what I want is to convert $\mathcal{N}$ as $k\mathcal{D}$.

Comment: Use $\lim_{b\to\infty}$ for the integral in the denominator so that it looks like $\int_1^b$. You could also split the integral in the numerator into $\int_0^1 \frac{ln(x)*ln(x)}{(1-x)(1-x)}$

Comment: How shall I proceed then?

Comment: Do we have convergence for the integral in the denominator?

Comment: Going off what @dan_fulea said, you'll have the also use $\lim_{a\to\infty}$ for your lower limit because when $x=1$ the integral DNE.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake while solving, I edited the question

Comment: This site https://www.integral-calculator.com/ will solve integrals in a step-by-step solution which yields a solution of $-2$.

Comment: "Integral equation" is not the right term for this. For one thing, it's not an equation. An integral equation does not identify a particular function and ask what its integral is; rather it involves a relationship between a not-yet-identified function and an integral involving it.

Comment: It could be useful to re-write denominator using $t=\frac1{x}$:
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal D &=& \int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{(1-x)x}dx=\\
&=&-\int_0^1\frac{-\log t}{\left(1-\frac1{t}\right)\frac1{t}}\left(-\frac1{t^2}\right)dt=\\
&=&-\int_0^1\frac{\log t}{t-1}dt
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrating the denominator by parts leads to

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal D &=& \int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{(1-x)x}dx=\\
&=& \frac12\left[\frac{\log^2 x}{(1-x)}\right]_1^{+\infty}-\frac12\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\log^2x}{(1-x)^2}dx=\\
&=&-\frac12\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\log^2x}{(1-x)^2}dx=\\
&\stackrel{t=\frac1{x}}{=}&-\frac12\int_1^0\frac{\log^2t}{\left(1-\frac1{t}\right)^2}\left(-\frac1{t^2}\right)dt=\\
&=&-\frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2 t}{(1-t)^2}dt = \\
&=&-\frac12 \cdot\mathcal N,
\end{eqnarray}
where $\mathcal N$ is your numerator. So 
$$\frac{\mathcal N}{\mathcal D}=-2.$$

Answer (score 1):

We have that by parts

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\ln\left(x\right)}{\left(1-x\right)x}}dx=\left[\dfrac{\ln^2\left(x\right)}{\left(1-x\right)}\right]_1^\infty-\int_{1}^{\infty}{\frac{\ln x}{x(1-x)}+\dfrac{\ln^2\left(x\right)}{\left(1-x\right)^2}}dx$$

$$\implies \int_{1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\ln\left(x\right)}{\left(1-x\right)x}}dx=-\frac12\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\ln^2\left(x\right)}{\left(1-x\right)^2}}dx$$

and by $y=\frac1x$

$$-\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\ln^2\left(x\right)}{\left(1-x\right)^2}}dx=-\int_{0}^{1}{\dfrac{\ln^2\left(y\right)}{\left(1-y\right)^2}}dx$$